# Tell Microsoft SQL Server Management to show 2 specific entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database management class assignment, the teacher wants us to create a request that will pull the first and last name of 2 passengers with their id numbers.

The table (`PASSAGER`) used for that assignment has the following columns:

- `ID_PASS` (the id number of the passengers)
- `NOM` (the last name of the passengers)
- `PRENOM` (the first name of the passengers)
- `CODE` (a unique code created by the airline company to identify each passenger which is a combination of their last name, first name and number of their civic address (the address where the passenger live))
- `NO_CIVIQUE` (the number of their civic address)
- `RUE` (the name of the street where the passenger lives)
- `LOCALITE` (the city/town/municipality where the passenger lives)
- `REF` (a reference number, I asked the teacher what was the specific role of that number but he didn't know what it was for, the only thing we know is that it isn't unique to each passenger and is therefore shared between passengers)
- `ID_PAYS` (the id of the country where the passenger comes from)
- `NOPASSPT` (the passport number of the passenger)

Like I said, we need to pull the last name (`NOM`) and first name (`PRENOM`) of 2 specific passengers with their id number (`ID_PASS`), specifically the ones with the number 344 and 346 so I did something like this:

```
SELECT NOM, PRENOM
FROM PASSAGER
WHERE ID_PASS = 344 AND 346
```

The request worked... Sort of, it did showed the columns `NOM` and `PRENOM` but they were empty.

My guest on why it didn't worked would be that the condition

```
WHERE ID_PASS = 344 AND 346
```

isn't the right syntax or the right way to do it, but I feel I'm on the right track.

I've also tried:

```
SELECT NOM, PRENOM
FROM PASSAGER
WHERE ID_PASS = 344, 346
```

But that one just gave me an error and it failed.

So yeah I'm kinda stuck on that one

Comment: Try something like `WHERE x = 1 AND x = 2`, or perhaps `WHERE x = 1 OR x = 2` (which also can be written as `WHERE x IN (1, 2)`.)

Comment: You want `WHERE ID_PASS IN (344, 346)`. SQL is all about sets of things.

Comment: This is about boolean logic, which you should have learned about in the first year ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is a logic problem. The `ID_PASS` cannot be both 344 and 346 at the same time, so do not use `AND` - you want to use `OR`. The `ID_PASS` is either 344 or 346. There are two ways to do this - one is to use `OR`, the other is to use `IN` (which is just a shortcut or syntactical sugar for `OR`).

Using `OR`:

```sql
SELECT NOM, PRENOM
FROM PASSAGER
WHERE ID_PASS = 344 OR ID_PASS = 346;
```

Using `IN`:

```sql
SELECT NOM, PRENOM
FROM PASSAGER
WHERE ID_PASS IN (344, 346);
```